# fopen_s returns error code 2 with system account and win 32 but works fine on winx64 (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, fopen, win32-process, win64

I have a cpp program that uses fopen_s to open and read a file created under the directory C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming.

My program needs to be compatible with winx64 and win32.

When I run this program with a system account (run using PSTools\PSExec -i  -s  C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe) and the Win32 compiled version of the program, fopen_s() on any file inside "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming" returns an error code 2, even though the file is present.
However, when I run the x64 compiled version of the same program, it works fine and fopen_s() is able to find and open the same file.

I am sure there are no mistakes as far as passing a valid filename to fopen_s() and I have verified this.

I make sure that the int variable that stores the return value from fopen_s() is set to 0 every time before calling fopen_s(). I am calling fopen_s() in "r" mode.

Also, elsewhere in the same program I am able to create files under the same directory.

I am using VS2019 and cpp +11 to compile my program.
My system is running windows 10 (64-bit) on an x64 processor (Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6136)

Why would a win32 application fail to read a file created under "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming" with a system account while the x64 version of the same application works fine?

Code snippet:

```
int FileOpenFunc(FILE ** ppFile, std::string sFilename, std::string sOpenMode)
{
    int errOpen = 0;
#ifdef _WIN32
    errOpen = fopen_s(ppFile, sFilename.c_str(), sOpenMode.c_str());
#else
    *ppFile = fopen(sFilename.c_str(), sOpenMode.c_str());
    errOpen = errno;
#endif
    return errOpen;
}

void func()
{
    std::string sFileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Roaming\\Check\\sample.txt";
    int errFopenErrNo = 0;
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    errFopenErrNo = FileOpenFunc(&fp, sFileName, "r");

    if (fp!= NULL)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: From information you have provided, one can only guess. It could be a problem in your code (e.g. pointer molestation or some other form of undefined behaviour that gives an observable symptom when built one way and not another).  It could be something else entirely. For people to help you, provide a [mcve] - a small but complete sample of code (irrelevant code omitted) that others can use to get the same symptoms. Specify compiler versions, compilation options, etc. When cutting down the code sample, you might have an "aha!" moment - and, if not, others have a better chance of helping.

Comment: A 32-bit process gets redirected to c:\windows\syswow64